# How to simulate viscous forces on the entire model or links?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am working on the simulation of an underwater vehicle. I have found ways to add viscous damping forces on the joints. But in my case I need to create a world that applies viscous drag on the entire vehicle.Please help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7636/how-to-simulate-viscous-forces-on-the-entire-model-or-links-??/) by [tejdeep](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1045/tejdeep/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You will have to write a plugin to handle this. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/2a9846c5aa4190de8afa23169e6423f6c7f8829a/plugins/MudPlugin.cc?at=default) is some example code that applies drag to links.

The above link to the mud plugin could be used as a crude simulation of water. Just make a large box that has the mud plugin attached to it, turn off or lower gravity, and put your vehicle inside the box. Make sure your vehicle uses [collide_without_contact](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=collision#contact_collide_without_contact).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tejdeep](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1045/tejdeep/) on 2014-12-06**:
Thanks a lot. That was quite useful. But since viscous drag depends on dot product of area and velocity, does just setting one damping value take care of the different drag forces that arise when the vehicle moves in x,y,z directions?? In other words is the damping value we set, the viscosity of the medium ??

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-12-08**:
Sadly, that example plugin uses the same parameter for each direction. Can you [create an issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new) for this feature request? I think it would be a great addition to gazebo.